# Preserve formatting of ColumnCalculations while downloading pdf from tabulator

Tags: grouping, jspdf, calculated-columns, formatter, tabulator

**Issue:** While downloading through tabulator all the column formatting is removed. I am aware of using accessors to reformat the data before downloading. This way I can define formatting for individual columns. However, for column calculations, *I am unable to define formatting for calculation results at the time of downloading in pdf format. In addition, I want row groups headers to have proper indentation as its available in tabulator.*

**Implemented code:**

```
var tabledata = [
              {
                  "Department": "Dept1",
                  "Promo Name": "$2 Off",
                  "Menu": "BURGER",
                  "Check #": "111",
                  "Settled By": "aaaaa",
                  "Discount By": "aaaaa",
                  "Price": "12.50",
                  "Discount": "2.00",
                  "Count of PromoID": "1"
              },
              {
                  "Department": "Dept1",
                  "Promo Name": "$2 Off",
                  "Menu": "soda",
                  "Check #": "1112",
                  "Settled By": "emp2",
                  "Discount By": "emp2",
                  "Price": "11.95",
                  "Discount": "2.00",
                  "Count of PromoID": "1"
              },
              {
                  "Department": "Dept1",
                  "Promo Name": "10% Off",
                  "Menu": "BURGER",
                  "Check #": "112",
                  "Settled By": "aaaaa",
                  "Discount By": "aaaaa",
                  "Price": "12.50",
                  "Discount": "0.00",
                  "Count of PromoID": "1"
              },
              {
                  "Department": "Dept1",
                  "Promo Name": "10% Off",
                  "Menu": "Water",
                  "Check #": "1122",
                  "Settled By": "aaaaa",
                  "Discount By": "aaaaa",
                  "Price": "1.85",
                  "Discount": "0.00",
                  "Count of PromoID": "1"
              },
              {
                  "Department": "Dept1",
                  "Promo Name": "222",
                  "Menu": "menu2",
                  "Check #": "1134",
                  "Settled By": "emp3",
                  "Discount By": "emp3",
                  "Price": "10.25",
                  "Discount": "2.00",
                  "Count of PromoID": "1"
              },
              {
                  "Department": "Dept1",
                  "Promo Name": "meal",
                  "Menu": "pizza",
                  "Check #": "1156",
                  "Settled By": "emp3",
                  "Discount By": "emp3",
                  "Price": "12.95",
                  "Discount": "6.48",
                  "Count of PromoID": "1"
              },
              {
                  "Department": "Dept1",
                  "Promo Name": "meal",
                  "Menu": "BURGER",
                  "Check #": "11562",
                  "Settled By": "aaaaa",
                  "Discount By": "aaaaa",
                  "Price": "12.50",
                  "Discount": "3.13",
                  "Count of PromoID": "1"
              },
              {
                  "Department": "Dept1",
                  "Promo Name": "meal",
                  "Menu": "sandwich",
                  "Check #": "157",
                  "Settled By": "emp2",
                  "Discount By": "emp2",
                  "Price": "56.25",
                  "Discount": "28.13",
                  "Count of PromoID": "1"
              },
              {
                  "Department": "Dept1",
                  "Promo Name": "meal",
                  "Menu": "coke",
                  "Check #": "27818",
                  "Settled By": "aaaaa",
                  "Discount By": "aaaaa",
                  "Price": "3.00",
                  "Discount": "1.50",
                  "Count of PromoID": "1"
              },
              {
                  "Department": "Dept1",
                  "Promo Name": "meal",
                  "Menu": "juice",
                  "Check #": "13346",
                  "Settled By": "aaaaa",
                  "Discount By": "aaaaa",
                  "Price": "3.00",
                  "Discount": "1.50",
                  "Count of PromoID": "1"
              }
          ];


          const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
              style: 'currency',
              currency: 'USD',
              minimumFractionDigits: 2
          })

          var colMoneyFormatter = function (value, data, type, params, column) {
              return formatter.format(value);
          }

          //create Tabulator on DOM element with id "example-table"
          var table = new Tabulator("#example-table",
              {
                  //height: 205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
                  data: tabledata //assign data to table
                  ,
                  layout: "fitData" //fit columns to width of table (optional)
                  ,
                  groupClosedShowCalcs: [true, true],
                  columnCalcs: "both",
                  groupBy: ["Department", "Promo Name"],
                  groupStartOpen: [true, true],
                  groupHeader: function(value, count, data, group) {
                      return value + "<span style='color:#d00; margin-left:10px;'>(" + count + " item)</span>";
                  },
                  groupToggleElement: ["arrow", "arrow"],
                  columns: [
                      { title: "Department", field: "Department", formatter: "plaintext" },
                      { title: "Promo Name", field: "Promo Name", formatter: "plaintext" },
                      { title: "Description", field: "Menu", formatter: "plaintext" }, {
                          title: "Price",
                          field: "Price",
                          accessorDownload: colMoneyFormatter,
                          formatter: "money",
                          bottomCalc: "sum",
                          bottomCalcParams: { precision: 2 },
                          bottomCalcFormatter: "money",
                          bottomCalcFormatterParams: {
                              decimal: ".",
                              thousand: ",",
                              symbol: "$"
                          },
                          formatterParams: {
                              decimal: ".",
                              thousand: ",",
                              symbol: "$"
                          }
                      }, {
                          title: "Discount",
                          field: "Discount",
                          accessorDownload: colMoneyFormatter,
                          formatter: "money",
                          bottomCalc: "sum",
                          bottomCalcParams: { precision: 2 },
                          bottomCalcFormatter: "money",
                          bottomCalcFormatterParams: {
                              decimal: ".",
                              thousand: ",",
                              symbol: "$"
                          },
                          formatterParams: {
                              decimal: ".",
                              thousand: ",",
                              symbol: "$"
                          }
                      }, { title: "Check #", field: "Check #", formatter: "plaintext" },
                      { title: "Settled By", field: "Settled By", formatter: "plaintext" },
                      { title: "Discount By", field: "Discount By", formatter: "plaintext" }
                  ]
              });

          //trigger download of data.pdf file
          $("#download-pdf").click(function () {
              table.download("pdf",
                  "data.pdf",
                  {
                      orientation: "landscape" //set page orientation to portrait
                      ,
                      title: "Detailed Promo Report" //add title to report
                      ,
                      autoTable: {
                          margin: {
                              top: 60
                          }
                      }
                  });
          });
```

**I want my pdf to look exactly like tabulator table with some additional rows, headers, and footers.**

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.2.7/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf-autotable/3.0.5/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<button id="download-pdf">Download PDF</button>
<div id="example-table"></div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
  var tabledata = [{
    "Department": "Dept1",
    "Promo Name": "$2 Off",
    "Menu": "BURGER",
    "Check #": "111",
    "Settled By": "aaaaa",
    "Discount By": "aaaaa",
    "Price": "12.50",
    "Discount": "2.00",
    "Count of PromoID": "1"
  },
    {
      "Department": "Dept1",
      "Promo Name": "$2 Off",
      "Menu": "soda",
      "Check #": "1112",
      "Settled By": "emp2",
      "Discount By": "emp2",
      "Price": "11.95",
      "Discount": "2.00",
      "Count of PromoID": "1"
    },
    {
      "Department": "Dept1",
      "Promo Name": "10% Off",
      "Menu": "BURGER",
      "Check #": "112",
      "Settled By": "aaaaa",
      "Discount By": "aaaaa",
      "Price": "12.50",
      "Discount": "0.00",
      "Count of PromoID": "1"
    },
    {
      "Department": "Dept1",
      "Promo Name": "10% Off",
      "Menu": "Water",
      "Check #": "1122",
      "Settled By": "aaaaa",
      "Discount By": "aaaaa",
      "Price": "1.85",
      "Discount": "0.00",
      "Count of PromoID": "1"
    },
    {
      "Department": "Dept1",
      "Promo Name": "222",
      "Menu": "menu2",
      "Check #": "1134",
      "Settled By": "emp3",
      "Discount By": "emp3",
      "Price": "10.25",
      "Discount": "2.00",
      "Count of PromoID": "1"
    },
    {
      "Department": "Dept1",
      "Promo Name": "meal",
      "Menu": "pizza",
      "Check #": "1156",
      "Settled By": "emp3",
      "Discount By": "emp3",
      "Price": "12.95",
      "Discount": "6.48",
      "Count of PromoID": "1"
    },
    {
      "Department": "Dept1",
      "Promo Name": "meal",
      "Menu": "BURGER",
      "Check #": "11562",
      "Settled By": "aaaaa",
      "Discount By": "aaaaa",
      "Price": "12.50",
      "Discount": "3.13",
      "Count of PromoID": "1"
    },
    {
      "Department": "Dept1",
      "Promo Name": "meal",
      "Menu": "sandwich",
      "Check #": "157",
      "Settled By": "emp2",
      "Discount By": "emp2",
      "Price": "56.25",
      "Discount": "28.13",
      "Count of PromoID": "1"
    },
    {
      "Department": "Dept1",
      "Promo Name": "meal",
      "Menu": "coke",
      "Check #": "27818",
      "Settled By": "aaaaa",
      "Discount By": "aaaaa",
      "Price": "3.00",
      "Discount": "1.50",
      "Count of PromoID": "1"
    },
    {
      "Department": "Dept1",
      "Promo Name": "meal",
      "Menu": "juice",
      "Check #": "13346",
      "Settled By": "aaaaa",
      "Discount By": "aaaaa",
      "Price": "3.00",
      "Discount": "1.50",
      "Count of PromoID": "1"
    }
  ];


  const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'USD',
    minimumFractionDigits: 2
  })

  var colMoneyFormatter = function(value, data, type, params, column) {
    return formatter.format(value);
  }


  const table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data: tabledata,
    layout: "fitData",
    groupClosedShowCalcs: [true, true],
    columnCalcs: "both",
    groupBy: ["Department", "Promo Name"],
    groupStartOpen: [true, true],
    groupHeader: function(value, count, data, group) {
      return value + "<span style='color:#d00; margin-left:10px;'>(" + count + " item)</span>";
    },
    groupToggleElement: ["arrow", "arrow"],
    columns: [{
      title: "Department",
      field: "Department",
      formatter: "plaintext"
    },
      {
        title: "Promo Name",
        field: "Promo Name",
        formatter: "plaintext"
      },
      {
        title: "Description",
        field: "Menu",
        formatter: "plaintext"
      }, {
        title: "Price",
        field: "Price",
        accessorDownload: colMoneyFormatter,
        formatter: "money",
        bottomCalc: "sum",
        bottomCalcParams: {
          precision: 2
        },
        bottomCalcFormatter: "money",
        bottomCalcFormatterParams: {
          decimal: ".",
          thousand: ",",
          symbol: "$"
        },
        formatterParams: {
          decimal: ".",
          thousand: ",",
          symbol: "$"
        }
      }, {
        title: "Discount",
        field: "Discount",
        accessorDownload: colMoneyFormatter,
        formatter: "money",
        bottomCalc: "sum",
        bottomCalcParams: {
          precision: 2
        },
        bottomCalcFormatter: "money",
        bottomCalcFormatterParams: {
          decimal: ".",
          thousand: ",",
          symbol: "$"
        },
        formatterParams: {
          decimal: ".",
          thousand: ",",
          symbol: "$"
        }
      }, {
        title: "Check #",
        field: "Check #",
        formatter: "plaintext"
      },
      {
        title: "Settled By",
        field: "Settled By",
        formatter: "plaintext"
      },
      {
        title: "Discount By",
        field: "Discount By",
        formatter: "plaintext"
      }
    ]
  });

  //trigger download of data.pdf file
  $("#download-pdf").click(function(){
    table.download("pdf", "data.pdf", {
      orientation:"portrait", //set page orientation to portrait
      title:"Example Report" //add title to report
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @dota2pro for responding. I need one more clarification as in tabulator for the given code, the sum is happening for sub-group only (in this case 'Promo Name'). The sum is not performed on the main group(in this case 'Department'). Please point out the mistake in my code or let me know if I have skipped something.

Comment: @SakshiGupta see my edit, sum will not happen on Dept1 row doesnt have any data

Comment: In addition to my previous issue, there are few more things that need clarification as 1) The overall total is not coming in the PDF export. 2) Adding more groups does not display the total for all groups as in this case for 'Dept1'. As per your comment, 'Dept1' has 10 records so I am not sure with what you meant by _'sum will not happen on Dept1 row doesnt have any data'_. Anyhelp will be greatly apprecaiated.

Comment: @SakshiGupta Did you get RED color in PDF export, which is display at UI?